# Querying a table for an uservariable list

Tags: mysql, database, variables, user-variables

I have the following Problem:
I have a table `table1` with multiple columns `col1` through `col2`:

```
+------+------+  
| col1 | col2 |    
+------+------+  
|  1   |  4   |  
|  2   |  4   |  
|  3   |  4   |  
|  4   |  5   |  
+------+------+
```

Now I need all entries `col1`-entries with a four in in `col2`, for which I use:

```
SELECT @col2fours := col1 FROM table1 WHERE col2 = 4;
```

Now I have a `table2` where I want to set the rows where `col3` has one of the values stored in `@col2fours`. For this I use:

```
SELECT * ID FROM table2 WHERE col3 IN @col2fours;
```

This doesn't work. I already tried `=` and `having` instead of `in` as well as using `Group_concat`. Nothing worked for me so far.
I would like to do this directly in mySQL because the database lies on a server and I want to reduce accesses to the database as much as possible. The real problem has somewhat more tables involved than 2 ;).
Appreciate any input, thanks.

Comment: 'Now I have a table2 where I want to set the rows where col3 has one of the values stored in @col2fours.' explain this

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use sub query like this directly

```
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE col3 IN (SELECT col1 FROM table1 WHERE col2 = 4);
```

Comment: Thanks, hadn't thought of something like this ;)

Answer (score 1):

This approach is a no-go, since in MySQL there is no array data type, so a variable can hold only 1 value at a time.

Just use a subquery or join to achieve the expected results:

```
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE col3 IN (SELECT col1 FROM table1 WHERE col2 = 4)

SELECT table2.* FROM table2
INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.col3=table1.col1
WHERE table1.col2 = 4
```

Comment: Thanks! I think the subquery is the way to go for me, the join seems a bit inappropriate for my problem, but thanks for your help!